# tox can't detect python interpreter in D:\python27 path

Tags: python, python-2.7, tox

My tox.ini file looks like this

```
[tox]
envlist=py27

[testenv]
deps=
    pytest
```

This fails to find my base python installation which is at D:\python27 and not the standard c:\python27 location

If I change tox.ini to  this, it works but looks ugly.

```
[tox]
envlist=cpy27,dpy27
skip_missing_interpreters=True
toxworkdir={toxinidir}/build/tox

[testenv]
basepython=
    cpy27: C:\Python27\python.exe
    dpy27: D:\Python27\python.exe

deps=
    pytest
```

so my question, how can I configure tox so it can figure out where python is installed on the windows machine, w/o explicitly specifying the paths as each developer may have it installed it in a different path on their machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured this out.
looks like I need to specify python2.7 instead of py27 for windows

```
[tox]
envlist=python2.7
```

This correctly detects the location of python irrespective of C or D drive.

Comment: `python2.7` is just unknown environment name for `tox`, it only makes `tox` to use the current Python interpreter (if the environment doesn't specify `basepython`), instead of forcing it to use Python 2.7. You can put any other numbers there and it will always use the current Python. Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve this, but this might be relevant: https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/114

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days I figure out how to setup the windows 10 without changing `tox.ini`, Follow the steps to get python2 and python3 setup in windows 10.

Make sure you installed python 2.7.16 which comes with its own pip. Install python 3 any version you want. Also make sure that you select custom installation and select available for all users checkbox during installation.

Now if you have python 2.7 in `C:/python27` and python 3 in `C:/program files/python36` then the following should be your system `path` environment variables. Remember the order is important.

[image]

Following files should be in your `python27` directory.

[image]

Following files should be in `Scripts` of `python27`

[image]

Following files should be in `python36` directory, duplicate `python.exe`

[image]

Following files should be in `python36 scripts` directory

[image]

After all the above setups, you should get all in path like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tox plugin [tox-globinterpreter](https://pypi.org/project/tox-globinterpreter/) to specify the paths where you have installed interpreters on your machine without having to change `tox.ini`, which is especially useful if your code is shared with other people.

Just install this plugin with `pip` and configure the paths using `tox --scan` (use forward slashes):

```
pip install tox_globinterpreter
tox --scan D:/Python*/python.exe
```

Afterwards, tox will be able to find your Python installation.